# prevent var_dump() return value auto print , echo

Tags: php, web-deployment

```
<?php
if ($row['enable_register'] == 'enabled' AND var_dump($row['s_time'] >= new DateTime('now')))
{
    echo CheckRegistration($row['enable_register'], $row['attendance_no'], $row['volunteers_no'], $row['preformers_no'], $row['id']);
}
?>
```

when if( condition ) is false the var_dump() returns bool(false) value and it's echoing it , it's not suppose to echo the return value .  I just want to check the return value whether it's true or false

Answer (score 0):

To be able to check the return value from your `checkRegistration` function, you should properly use the if statement and the conditions as well.

1.first, **the appropriate use of `var_dump`** would be:
`var_dump(CheckRegistration($row['enable_register'] , $row['attendance_no'],$row['volunteers_no'],$row['preformers_no'], $row['id'] ))`
It is used to dump information and returns type and value.
It is therefore not appropriate to use it as a condition in the if statement.

**2. Secondly, Formatting DateTime Object**
You need to format the datetime object to get the desired time format that suits your if condition: For example;
`$obj = new DateTime(); $now = $obj->format('Y/m/d s:i:H'));`
Note:
In `DateTime` constructor definition `now` is default value for initializing string:

`public DateTime::__construct() ([ string $time = "now" [, DateTimeZone $timezone = NULL ]] )`
Therefore `$date = new DateTime()` and `$date = new DateTime('now')` are the same

**3. Comparison**
When working with date strings, you should convert them to timestamp using `strtotime` in order to compare their value. However, `DateTime` objects work with comparison operators. You can directly compare two DateTime object: For example:
`

```
$today = new DateTime('today');
 $yesterday = new DateTime('yesterday');
 var_dump($today > $yesterday);
 var_dump($today < $yesterday);
 var_dump($today == $yesterday);
 // Output
 bool(true)
 bool(false)
 bool(false)
```

`
References:

- https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.construct.php
- https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime